# Apply using multiple rows in vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I'd like to do some math on a series vector. I'd like to take the difference between two rows in a vector. My first intuition was:

```
def row_diff(prev, next):
   return(next - prev)
```

and then using it

```
my_col_vec.apply(row_diff)
```

but this doesn't do what I'd like. It appears apply is row-wise, which is fine, but I can't seem to find an equivalent operation that will allow me to easy create a new vector from the old one by subtracting the previous row from the next.

Is there a better way to do this? I've been reading [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html) document and it doesn't look like it.

Thanks!

Comment: use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html)

Comment: @EdChum Please post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate inter-row differences use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
In [6]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.rand(5)})
df

Out[6]:
          a
0  0.525220
1  0.031826
2  0.260853
3  0.273792
4  0.281368

In [7]:
df['diff'] = df['a'].diff()
df

Out[7]:
          a      diff
0  0.525220       NaN
1  0.031826 -0.493394
2  0.260853  0.229027
3  0.273792  0.012940
```

Also please try to avoid using `apply` as there is usually a vectorised method available